# split m4b with chapters to multiple mp3?

Tags: pydub

I've written a python command line script to convert an m4b file that may or may not have chapters into either a single mp3 (if no chapters) or multiple mp3's (one file per chapter) however its very clunky.

If you drop the script into a folder which has multiple m4b's either at the top level or in child folders it will process them all.

It's the splitting the chapters into multiple mp3's that's important.

However I've just discovered pydub.

Would this be easy with pydub?

How would I do it in an elegant way?

Thanks, A